# Regex - match string against the array of regular expressions

Tags: regex, expression

I have a problem with regex and need your help.

I'm trying to extract objName "AAAA"`s valueList with regex from below example.

I want extract 1111.0, 2222.0, 3333.0 for each group of regex.

Is there a way in Regex Expression to get 1111.0, 2222.0, 3333.0 in 3 groups?

Here`s my demo -> http://regex101.com/r/E1DE2R/1

```
"result": [
        {
            "objName": "AAAA"
            "timeList": [
                "1629166200446",
                "1629166202448",
                "1629166204449"
            ],
            "valueList": [
                "1111.0",
                "2222.0",
                "3333.0"
            ]
        },
        {
            "objName": "BBBB"
            "timeList": [
                "1629166200446",
                "1629166202448",
                "1629166204449"
            ],
            "valueList": [
                "4444.0",
                "5555.0",
                "6666.0"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Which tool/language/framework will you be using to apply your regex?

Comment: Regexps are not so good at nested contexts, so if you tell us what you are doing this within, we can offer up some tricks...

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen i`m trying to use regex101, here is my DEMO https://regex101.com/r/E1DE2R/1 thanks

Comment: @ChrisMaurer I`m trtying to user regex101, here is my DEMO https://regex101.com/r/E1DE2R/1 thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Regular expressions can not capture a dynamic number of matches very well.
If you are sure there are always 3 array entries, you can use this:

```regex
"valueList"\:\s\[\s+(\"([0-9\.]+)\")([,\s]*\"([0-9\.]+)\")([,\s]*\"([0-9\.]+)\")
```

Solution available here:
https://regex101.com/r/j2Zbfp/1

You can tweak this to find a certain maximum number of values, but it will not work forever.

```regex
"valueList"\:\s\[\s+(\"([0-9\.]+)\")([,\s]*\"([0-9\.]+)\")?([,\s]*\"([0-9\.]+)\")?([,\s]*\"([0-9\.]+)\")?([,\s]*\"([0-9\.]+)\")?([,\s]*\"([0-9\.]+)\")?
```

You can repeat the `([,\s]*\"([0-9\.]+)\")?` part for as many matches as you need.
As you can see this is not acceptable if the data is allowed to grow arbitrarily big.

The example seems to be a JSON object - why not parse and process it instead?

Answer (score 0):

Try the below regEx

"valueList": [(((\s*"(\d*.\d)")(,?))*)

[image]